# highlight comment in VIM

Tags: vim

I've tried to set comment to something different than blue, but it doesn't work. My .vimrc:

```
syntax enable
hi comment ctermfg=yellow
hi number ctermfg=14
```

The number works, but comments not. It just flash to yellow, but than it is blue. I even try it with the number instead of yellow, but with the sma result. If I post this command in running vim with :, it works fine.
Thank you.

Comment: Is that your entire .vimrc?

Comment: you may have something else further down in your .vimrc or some other plugin that is overriding that setting.

Comment: Thank you, but it is my whole .vimrc. Only problem could be, is there any other configuration file?